# MacBook Pro Function key + Command/Option hotkeys problem

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut, touch-bar

I'm using Intellij Idea on Mac, that heavily utilizes hotkeys including Function keys + the <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> keys.

While hardware keys + the <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> keys work okay, Touch Bar keys + the <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> keys pressed don't register the combination, essentially breaking so many hotkey commands in Idea.

Has anyone been able to resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I've taken the liberty of editing your question and as part of that have removed your last sentence: *Is there a care for Apple's innovative approach or useless touch bar?*. I assume this wasn't the reason for your post and felt it would distract from the main objective. As for your issue, can I suggest you also edit your question to include what you've already tried? Otherwise you may get a lot of answers suggesting things you've already done.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing a solution to this problem, although it's pretty uncommon case.
Root cause of the problem was Karabiner elements setup.
They have a ticket open corresponding to this case:
https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1160

What you need to do to start registering this hotkeys is essentially enable unknown devices in Karabiner settings.